# Active model serializer - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to serialize a nested collection. I have a product with images. But when I try a `has_many` or an explicit method to define an `images` attribute in my product serializer, I get:

`wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

I could have sworn this was doable. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
class Api::V1::ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :sku, :name, :description, :images

  def images
    object.images
  end
end
```

---

**Full backtrace**

```
Started GET "/api/v1/products" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-03-02 23:12:34 +0000
Processing by Api::V1::ProductsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "tenant_users" ON "tenant_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "tenant_users"."tenant_id" = 1 AND "users"."authentication_token" = 'pGJE5UWrxzJTEPxMyiez'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["current_sign_in_at", "2015-03-02 23:12:34.913333"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2015-03-02 23:12:33.754114"], ["sign_in_count", 171], ["updated_at", "2015-03-02 23:12:34.914298"]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."tenant_id" = 1
  Attachinary::File Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "attachinary_files".* FROM "attachinary_files"  WHERE "attachinary_files"."attachinariable_id" = $1 AND "attachinary_files"."attachinariable_type" = $2 AND "attachinary_files"."scope" = 'images'  [["attachinariable_id", 1], ["attachinariable_type", "Product"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb:4:in `index'
  app/controllers/concerns/api/landlord.rb:13:in `require_tenant!'


  Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (11.7ms)
```

Comment: Could you please provide full backtrace of `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error?